# How do I call elements of an array as their index numerical value

Tags: arrays, perl, foreach, splice

I have an @ORF array consisting of strings of different length. I want to get rid of strings of less than 50 characters, so I wrote the following foreach loop:

```
foreach (@ORF) {   
    if (length ($_) <= 50) {
            splice @ORF, ;
}
```

I want to know what the second argument of splice should be, I have googled around but I cannot find a way to call an element as a numerical value.

Comment: `splice` documentation is here: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html

Comment: You really don't want to add or remove array elements within the loop body.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd better use [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html):

```
@ORF = grep{ length($_) > 50 } @ORF;
```